# Blazor deserialization very slow

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I am using webassembly blazor .net 6.0, deserialization is very slow. I tried Newtonsoft.Json and XmlSerializer, both are in range 10-100 times slower in Blazor, than the same code in regular .net 6 code. I deserialize abstract list of classes and the concrete types are discovered when deserializing.
Does anybody have any ideas on how to do this kind of "complex" communication better?  I emphasize the polymorphic classes being deserialized.

Comment: Why are you serializing polymorphic objects? You do know that you can't serialize _methods_, only type-names, right? Have you run a profiler to see _where_ in the WASM it's slowing down?

Comment: i meant abstract classes, where the concrete type is determined using [XmlInclude] or ContractResolver in Newtonsoft
I am gonna see if and how profiling is used in WASM, that is a good point, thank you

Comment: Generally speaking it's a bad idea to serialize data such that you need to include type-names.

Comment: In .net 6.0 performance tips, they suggest replacing Newtonsoft with System.Text.Json, but its geared for app download size in that section, I don't know if it will accelerate the process.(Aspnet page on optimization) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/performance?view=aspnetcore-6.0#minimize-app-download-size . Feels like this is going to be a recurring subject with Blazor Wasm.

Comment: I am having a similar experience. The data from my API is about 3MB and it takes 5 times as long to get the data in web assembly than it does in a .Net 6.0 console app.